# Cronjob like using PHP

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to run a php file everyday at given time. I don't want to use cronJOB is there a another way to do it directly without using CronJOB. If so can you guide me to that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a cronjob manager, then use that to execute certain scripts at certain times from a central location. What's wrong with cronjobs?

Comment: I don't have access to UNIX system.

Comment: You won't have much ability to automate anything then... How steady is your traffic? You could include a script to check the time and a flag for whether the job has been processed yet, which would be run every time someone executes a page of your website - do your job, update the flag for the day. It's not ideal though as it will impact the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen an event, like site access and check the time, than execute a script. IN index.php

```
<?php if(date('H:i:s') > '00:00:00' && 
         date('H:i:s') < '01:00:00' && 
         date('Y-m-d') != file_get_contents('check.txt')){ 
                 file_put_contents('check.txt',date('Y-m-d')); 
                 /*your code*/ 
       }  ?>
```

This code will execute between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00 once a day. But if you have low trafic on a site the event will not pop up

Comment: You should add some more detail to this, it's not really an answer.

Comment: Nice - you'd want to factor in how long it takes to run `/* your code */` though, if it takes ten minutes to run then the script could overlap many times. Better to put the `file_put_contents()` call before `/* your code */`

Comment: Hmm. I don't want to access the php file. I want to do everything automatically. Like scheduling a job to run a php file on a particular time.

Comment: That is not posible. In that case you need some socket on the server side

Comment: Hmm.. That is bad! I will check if I can get cronjob access. Thanks anyways!